# Migrating Google Analytics Universal to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Im trying to migrate my google analytics Universal code to Google Tag Manager. Currently, I have added only the Global tracking code to my website. And haven't set up any events in Google Analytics. I need to know is it enough if I create the page view Tag in Google tag manager in the migration process or are there any default other tags i need to add to my project to migrate without any data loss.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are currently tracking is page views, then the page view tag is enough in GTM.

If you plan to use events in the future, you should consider using a "settings" variable - that's a variable type specially made for Universal Analytics that stores all common settings such as the tracking id, fields you might want to set and custom dimensions and metrics you might want to set on all your requests to Google Analytics. If you do not use a settings variable, you have to repeat all common settings on all tags.

Individual GA tags also allow you to override settings from the settings variable if necessary.

Comment: I have not setup any other additional events by adding codes to the website. Can I know does the Page view capture all the basic details available in Audience section and site speed etc @Eike